# Template argument deduction: which compiler is right here?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
template<int N>
class Vector
{
};

#include <array>

template<int N>
void doWork(const Vector<N>&, const std::array<int,N>&)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int,3> arr;
    Vector<3> vec;
    doWork(vec,arr);
}
```

Here `Vector` represents a class which is defined in a third-party library, and `std::array` is known to take its element count as `std::size_t`.

I've tried compiling this with clang-3.6 and g++-5.1. Clang worked without any complaint, while g++ gives the following error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:17:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘doWork(Vector<3>&, std::array<int, 3ul>&)’
     doWork(vec,arr);
                   ^
test.cpp:9:6: note: candidate: template<int N> void doWork(const Vector<N>&, const std::array<int, N>&)
 void doWork(const Vector<N>&, const std::array<int,N>&)
      ^
test.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:17:19: note:   mismatched types ‘int’ and ‘long unsigned int’
     doWork(vec,arr);
                   ^
test.cpp:17:19: note:   ‘std::array<int, 3ul>’ is not derived from ‘const std::array<int, N>’
```

I can work around this by doing a cast of `N` to `std::size_t` in second parameter of `doWork()` or calling `doWork<3>()`, but this wouldn't educate me.

So I rather ask first: which compiler is right here? Am I really doing something wrong in the code (so clang is too permissive), or is it indeed valid C++ (so that g++ has a bug)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe gcc is correct here, if we go to the draft C++11 standard section `14.8.2.5` *[temp.deduct.type]* it says:

> If, in the declaration of a function template with a non-type
>   template-parameter, the non-type templateparameter is used in an
>   expression in the function parameter-list and, if the corresponding
>   template-argument is deduced, the template-argument type shall match
>   the type of the template-parameter exactly, except that a
>   template-argument deduced from an array bound may be of any integral
>   type.144 [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<int i> class A { /* ... */ };
> template<short s> void f(A<s>);
> void k1() {
> A<1> a;
> f(a); // error: deduction fails for conversion from int to short
> f<1>(a); // OK
> }
> ```
>
> [...]

and we can see if we change your code to this:

```
doWork<3>(vec,arr);
```

gcc does not issue an error and neither does clang.

If we try this example:

```
template<int N>
void doWorkB( std::array<int,N>&)
{
}

//...

doWorkB(arr);
```

clang now produces an error (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aOQcOilDY9K5m46X)*):

```
note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure : deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the its corresponding template parameter ('unsigned long' vs 'int')
void doWorkB( std::array<int,N>&)
     ^
```

Your original case also breaks in clang if we swap the parameter order:

```
void doWork( const std::array<int,N>&, const Vector<N>& )
```