How do template specializations match non-type arguments of different types, and is there a difference betwen classes and type aliases?
The following program defines class A with a non-type template argument of type long.
This can be instantiated passing an int value, which is of course allowed because the int can be implicitly converted to long.
Now I define a type trait Is_A_1 to identify a specialization of A. So I define a primary template that derives from std::false_type, and a specialization taking the non-type template argument auto x, matching A<x>, and deriving from std::true_type. This works, so e.g. Is_A_1<A<7>>::value is true.
Then I define Is_A_2 which is a small variation of Is_A_1. The non-type template argument for the specialization is int x instead of auto x. This compiles in clang, but not in gcc (all versions supporting C++20).
Then I define the type alias template <int x> using B = A<x>, and define type traits Is_B_1 and Is_B_2 analogously to Is_A_1 and Is_A_2. These behave similarly on all compiler versions, except in gcc 14, Is_B_1<B<7>> is false.
My intuition is that clang is right and gcc is wrong, because all the cases are so similar that I feel they should give the same answer, but that's just intuition.
At https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters, section "Template non-type arguments", it says:

If T contains a placeholder type, or is a placeholder for a deduced class type, the type of the template parameter is the type deduced for the variable x in the invented declaration T x = E;, where E is the template argument provided for the parameter.

To me, this sounds as if the type for the auto argument is deduced from context, and the context is the int value 7. This makes me think that at least Is_A_1<A<7>>::value should be equal to Is_A_2<A<7>>::value and Is_B_1<B<7>>::value should be equal to Is_B_2<B<7>>::value.
But then gcc changed behavior in a higher version, making it stricter for type aliases. Since time moves forward and newer is better, it makes me wonder if the stricter behavior is more correct? But I'm just speculating.
Does the standard specify the behaviors in these cases?
#include <type_traits> // std::false_type

template <long x> class A {};
A<1> a; // OK

template <class T> struct Is_A_1        : public std::false_type {};
template <auto x>  struct Is_A_1<A<x>>  : public std::true_type {};
static_assert(Is_A_1<A<7>>::value); // OK

template <class T> struct Is_A_2       : public std::false_type {};
template <int x>   struct Is_A_2<A<x>> : public std::true_type {};
static_assert(Is_A_2<A<7>>::value); // Error in gcc, OK in clang

template <int x>  using B = A<x>;
B<1> b; // OK

template <class T> struct Is_B_1       : public std::false_type {};
template <auto x>  struct Is_B_1<B<x>> : public std::true_type {};
static_assert(Is_B_1<B<7>>::value); // OK everywhere except gcc 14 + trunk

template <class T> struct Is_B_2       : public std::false_type {};
template <int x>   struct Is_B_2<B<x>> : public std::true_type {};
static_assert(Is_B_2<B<7>>::value); // Error in gcc, OK in clang

I tried to compile the code above on Godbolt, and expected at least consistent behavior in all the cases. clang consistently accepts all cases (versions 10.0.0 through 19.1.0). But gcc fails when the type trait argument is int (versions 10.1 through 14.2), and also gcc version 14.* fails when the type we are testing is a type alias.

I think there are similar questions with some user traits using std::array and (wrong) int/(correct)std::size_t...

You should check if int and long are the same type.

static_assert(Is_B_1<B<7>>::value); // OK everywhere except gcc 14 - it is OK in gcc trunk as well: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e1Prs76oq

May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707139/implicit-type-conversion-between-size-t-and-int-using-templates

Thanks Fedor!
I added trunk to the example.
I believe the other question is related, and the defect report linked from the accepted answer may at least partially explain the inconsistent behavior here. (direct link: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1647 )
